# Python syntax errors

Tags: python

I am having a few problems with my code.. I am following an example in the book "Beginning Game Development with Python and Pygame" (example 2-4 and 2-5) and I am getting syntax errors. Below is the code in question. I am new to Python and probably just did a typo.

The book uses python 2.4. I'm getting the error for 2.7 and 3.2.

Two problems:

the code line with:

```
my_tank = Tank("Bob")
```

is receiving a syntax error. `my_tank` is highlighted. I did get it to start working but I am not sure why it started to.

The code line with:

```
print self.name, "fires on", enemy.name
```

is also recieveing a syntax error. The `self` in this line is highlighted. When `my_tank` stared working I started to receive this error. Not sure whats going on here.

```
class Tank(object):

    def _init_(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.alive = True
        self.ammo = 5
        self.armor = 60

    my_tank = Tank("Bob")

    def _str_(self):

        if self.alive:
            return "%s (%i armor, %i shells)" % (self.name, self.armor, self.ammo)
        else:
            return "%s (dead)" % self.name

    def fire_at(self, enemy):

        if self.ammo >= 1:
            self.ammo -= 1
            print self.name, "fires on", enemy.name
            enem.hit()
        else:
            print self.name, "has no shells!"

    def hit(self):

        self.armor -= 20
        print self.name, "is hit!"
        if self.armor <= 0:
            self.explode()

    def explode(self):

        self.alive = False
        print self.name, "explodes!"
```

Comment: Post the actual error you receive, including the entire traceback.  Also, it is important that you specify what Python version you're using, since their syntax differs (for instance in how `print` is used).  Do you get these errors with Python 2.7 or Python 3.2 or both?

Comment: A quick guess: you have `_init_` and `_str_` in your code, while the correct names for default methods are `__init__` and `__str__` (notice two underscores)

Comment: @aland: You're right, but that shouldn't produce a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: @LewisBellinger: Running in Python 2.7, that line gives a `NameError`, not a syntax error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @aland notes, the function names are supposed to be `__init__` and `__str__`.

Also, this line should be *outside* the class:

```
my_tank = Tank("Bob")
```

After all, you want an *instance* of the class for later use.

Comment: From a quick glance, you could also mention `enem.hit()` which should probably be `enemy.hit()`.

Comment: @sharth Hmm, he didn't mention a compiler error for that line in the question. Good catch!

Comment: Yes i didnt notice that i need two underscores under init and str and then moved my my_tank line to outside of the class.... the book didnt mention to do that... or i overlooked it? :p Thx for the help and i recieve no errors... sweet

Answer (score 2):

chrsaycock's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11822089/1322401) looks correct, but I want to emphasize how important it is to pay attention to the traceback you receive.

When I run your code I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#86>", line 1, in <module>
    class Tank(object):
  File "<pyshell#86>", line 9, in Tank
    my_tank = Tank("Bob")
NameError: name 'Tank' is not defined
```

Your question should have been something along the lines of "Why am i getting a `NameError` here?  I've defined `Tank` in line one."

Don't think of this error as a generic syntax error.  The *type* of the error tells you much of what you need to know.

Comment: Yes i didnt notice that i need two underscores under init and str and then moved my my_tank line to outside of the class.... the book didnt mention to do that... or i overlooked it? :p Thx for the help and i recieve no errors... sweet